# Getting error Stray end tag head

Tags: html

I am not sure what am I doing wrong. Is the image in the header or something else ? Tried inspecting and not able to come up with fix for the error. Help would be appreciated

```
    <head>
    <!-- Meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="Creating Web Applications" /> 
    <meta name="keywords" content="party equipment" />
    <meta name="author" content="Zaid Shakil" />

    <!--CSS Style File Link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />

    <!-- Title of the page -->
    <title>Party Equipment</title>
    <!-- Navigation bar -->

    <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html" class="home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="product.html" class="product">Product</a></li>
          <li><a href="enquiry.html" class="enquiry">Enquiry</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html" class="about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <img id="homepic" src="images/partyhome.png" alt="Party" />
</head>
```

Comment: `nav` or `img` elements should not appear in the head. You should move them to the body.

Comment: Img i accept but I thought we can can use nav bar in the head. I have seen a lot of websites doing it. Is it a bad practice ?

Comment: can you explain what error you are facing? Already @HashPsi pointed out your mistake.

Comment: perhaps you are confusing `head` with `header`, `head` is used for styles/scripts/meta that aren't displayed in the body of the page. Also, as @Bhushan pointed out, we are confused as to your error: The question's title isn't explained in the question itself.

Comment: @leftside yeah now it makes perfect sense. I confused head with header. Thanks mate !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through with this, [avoiding-common-html5-mistakes](http://html5doctor.com/avoiding-common-html5-mistakes/)

```
<head>
 <!-- Meta tags -->
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta name="description" content="Creating Web Applications" /> 
 <meta name="keywords" content="party equipment" />
 <meta name="author" content="Zaid Shakil" />

 <!--CSS Style File Link -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />

 <!-- Title of the page -->
 <title>Party Equipment</title>
 <!-- Navigation bar -->
</head>

<body>
   <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html" class="home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="product.html" class="product">Product</a></li>
      <li><a href="enquiry.html" class="enquiry">Enquiry</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html" class="about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
     </nav>

  <img id="homepic" src="images/partyhome.png" alt="Party" /> 
</body>
```